# Printing numbers which are powers of the 3. Can I code this program better?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file = open('funny_file.txt', 'r')
list = []
for i in file:
    list.append(int(i[:-1]))
print(len([num for num in list for i in range(100) if num == 3**i]))
```

The result is good but can i make it in other easier way?

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and output? It is pretty unclear now.

Comment: input: 40
30
120
33
145
27
64
24
201
100
343
5
7 and result should be 2

Comment: The only square of 3 is 9, do you mean powers? In that case you could just repeatedly apply `divmod(n, 3)` to the number as long as the remainder is 0 and the div is non-zero. If you find a non-zero remainder then it's not a power, if you reach a div of 1 then it is.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You are right, should be powers my mistake

Comment: A more efficient solution will probably use `math.log(num, 3)`.

Comment: First of all! The output you provide in the comment above should be 1. The only power of 3 in that input is `27`. Also, can we assume you won't get a power of 3 pass that `100` exponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the largest exponent is `100` (from your `range(100)`). You could do a fairly **O(1)** computation. First you can calculate `3^100` = `515377520732011331036461129765621272702107522001`. Now, this number divided by any power of 3 (smaller than this number) has a reminder of **0**. So you could write:

```
def check_power_of_three(n):
    return 515377520732011331036461129765621272702107522001 % n == 0
```

Now, about your code. I do not get why are you doing **two loops**, when you can achieve the same thing using just one.

```
file = open('funny_file.txt', 'r')
numList = [] # I changed the name to avoid conflicts with `list` type
powerOfThree = []
for i in file:
    n = int(i[:-1])
    numList.append(n)
    if check_power_of_three(n):
        powerOfThree.append(n)
print(len(powerOfThree))

# Also remember to close() the file
file.close()
```

**Outputs:**

`1`

^ Which is `27`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by 'square of the 3', you mean powers of three.

There are some things going on in your print statement that I would recommend you to revise. Generally, when you are interested in achieving a particular result, it makes sense to create a separate function for it that encapsulates that functionality. In this case, it could be a function that tells us whether it's input is a power of three. Using the logarithm with base three you should be able to come up with an implementation of that function.

Answer (score 0):

One way to optimize the code is to skip computation for the numbers which are already explored before, like below:

```
file = open('funny_file.txt', 'r')
list = []
for i in file:
    list.append(int(i[:-1]))
powerof_3_nums = []
not_power_of_3 = []
for num in list:
    if num in powerof_3_nums:
        continue
    if num in not_power_of_3:
        continue
    for i in range(100):
        if num == 3**i:
            powerof_3_nums.append(num)
print(len(powerof_3_nums))
```